# Поток ввода вывода

Tags: windows, c

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как запретить ввод букв, то есть, чтобы при нажатии на букву, на экране ничего не происходило?

Comment: А какой язык программирования?

Comment: @script
язык менее важен, на какой платформе и в какой среде.

Comment: Язык СИ,компилятор dev c++,оперционная система виндовс,нужно,чтобы работали тока цифры,буквы не отображались и игнорировались,ну и enter и back space чтобы работали

Comment: dev c++ - среда, а компилятор? (наверное, MinGW с++)

Answer (score 1):

Виндовс, C, правда MinGW gcc.
Что-то вроде этого:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main ()
{
  int c, i = 0;
  char c4[5];

  while ((c = getch()) != 26 ) { // ^Z text stdin EOF 
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      putchar(c);  fflush(stdout);
      c4[i++] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\b') {  // BS == 8
      printf ("\b \b");  fflush(stdout);
      if (--i < 0)
        i = 0;
      continue;
    }
    if (c == '\r' || i == 4) { // ENTER or Your 4 digits
      c4[i] = 0;
      printf ("\nMy %d digits: %s\n",i,c4);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Уважаемый ХэшКод!  А можно сделать, чтобы при Paste кода табуляции расширялись в правильное число пробелов ?

Comment: @avp Это хорошая идея, мы добавили ее в список задач, и в будущем, вероятно, сделаем. Сейчас нужно заменять табуляции на нужное количество пробелов перед вставкой вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте, например, функцию getch() (для С/C++). Она блокирует отображение вводимого с клавиатуры символа. При этом есть возможность проанализировать введенный символ.

Comment: Мне нужно,чтобы вводилось сразу 4 цифры

Answer (score 0):

Можно также перехватывать любое событие нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре для какого-либо контрола, окна либо консоли, и просто блокировать его, например в Delphi это keybd_event, wxPython - wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN и т.п.

Comment: Как это сделать в СИ?

Comment: В с++ есть функция getch(), которая проглатывает символ, для 4-х символов вызови ее 4 раза, это для консоли, а графического интерфейса, зависит от того в чем ты пишешь. Там для каждого элемента есть обработчики различных событий (event), в том числе и ввода символов